# Group exclusion in Nelmio Api Doc does not work After updating composer

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, nelmioapidocbundle

I set up a parameter as array, as described in http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations

```
class QuestionAnswer
{
    /**
   * @JMS\Type("ArrayCollection<Rest\Bundle\Entity\Fixture\QuestionOptions>")
     * @Groups({"QuestionAnswer"})
   */
      public $question_options_array ;
}
```

and define some options in another class

```
class QuestionOptions
{
    /**
       * @JMS\Type("integer")
       * @Groups({"get_option"})
       */
      public $question_option_id ;

      /**
       * @JMS\Type("string")
       * @Groups({"post_option"})
       */
      public $question_option_description;
}
```

In @ApiDoc I define

```
     * input={
     *      "class" = "Rest\BeautyBundle\Entity\Fixture\ProfileQuestionAnswer", 
     *      "groups"={"QuestionAnswer", "get_option"},
     *  },
```

Before updating it works well. But after `composer update` only the "QuestionAnswer" group name works and it shows all properties from QuestionOptions class.
How can I submit properties in the array the way it was before the update?

Comment: Seems like a bug on either library. You should go to NelmioApiDoc on github and report.

Comment: Try use `composer install` instead of `composer update`. Also you can change your composer.json to a previous version of this library?

Answer (score 1):

Wow quite odd. Something very similar happened with me in the past and It seems to be an API issue. Nothing on the code end that us developers can do. No one has found a workaround or fix either.

Answer (score 0):

> marcin-jozwikowski commented on Nov 25, 2020
>
> OK, I got it working!
> The answer is as old as it gets: clear the cache. At least that's what it was in my case.
> There's also a requirement in [Serializer manual](https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html#using-serialization-groups-annotations) to install `sensio/framework-extra-bundle` but it work for me without it.

Original comment: https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle/issues/1167#issuecomment-733909426